# Drawing text using CATiledLayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics

I have a `UIView` subclass `MyTextView` that I add to a `scrollView`, and it just has a bunch of text, but it gets to be really long sometimes (around 50,000 px high). Using regular drawing methods such as `NSString's` `drawInRect` method is apparently not the right way to do this, so now I'm looking into `CATiledLayer` to help me out with drawing the text. Unfortunately, there's not enough examples out there to help with drawing text with `CATiledLayer`, and I'm wondering if anyone knows how I can get started with this task.

Is using `CATiledLayer` my best option when it comes to drawing really long text in a UIScrollView?

(I don't want to use a `UITextView` since that's also scrollable - and even if I were to use it, I wouldn't want it to be scrollable, I'd set its frame to 50,000 px high, and that doesn't solve my problem (remember that I'll be adding this view to a scrollView, so a UITextView in a scrollView isn't exactly fun)).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know it CATiledLayer is the *best* but to get you started, you can draw the text content of each tile yourself.

Create the layer and set the delegate:

```
   CATiledLayer *tiledLayer = [CATiledLayer layer];
    tiledLayer.delegate = self;
    tiledLayer.tileSize =  CGSizeMake(768, 1024);
    tiledLayer.levelsOfDetail = 4;
    tiledLayer.levelsOfDetailBias = 2;
//etc.....
```

Then just to normal CGContext drawing code:

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
```

you can get the tile rect and/or scale for drawing

```
CGRect rect = CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(ctx);
CGFloat scale = CGContextGetCTM(ctx).a;
```

A word from the documentation on setting the layer delegate:

> In iOS, if the layer is associated with a UIView object, this property
>   must be set to the view that owns the layer.

Comment: What would I do with that layer after creating it? How would I add it to the view?

Comment: I did `[self.view.layer addSublayer:tiledLayer];
    [self.view.layer setNeedsDisplay];` but the delegate method never gets called..

Comment: Just a thought but have you set the tiledLayer frame?  Kind of hard to say with out some code.  You may try creating a separate delegate class to handle the drawLayer call, and instance that within your UIView class.